# Calculate the checksum/Hash of a BLOB field in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hash

I need to check if the hash of a parameter equals to the hash of a column in PostgreSQL.
In oracle I use the following code to do so

```
ORA_HASH(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(BlobField,2000,1))) <> ORA_HASH(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(:BlobField,2000,1)))
```

> I use the first 2000 bytes only because of a restriction in ORA_HASH function of Oracle, this is not needed for the PostgreSQL implementation

Is there anything equivalent in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regress=> SELECT md5('blah blah');
               md5                
----------------------------------
 ae661d08d1ca1576a6efcb82b7bc502f
(1 row)
```

This works with `bytea` fields too:

```
regress=> SELECT md5(BYTEA '\x000102');
               md5                
----------------------------------
 b95f67f61ebb03619622d798f45fc2d3
(1 row)
```

`BYTEA '\x000102'` is just a bytea literal for the example. You'd usually just write `md5(the_column)` and it'll work just fine for both text and bytea.

In any real test of course you'd always write:

```
SELECT blah, blah2
FROM tablename
WHERE md5(fieldname) = 'ae661d08d1ca1576a6efcb82b7bc502f' 
  AND fieldname = 'blah blah';
```

since a checksum is by its nature going to risk collisions, however unlikely. It's typical that you'd have an index on `md5(fieldname)` so you'd greatly reduce the number of full-field comparisons made, eg:

```
CREATE INDEX sometable_somefield_md5 ON sometable((md5(somefield));
```